# Is jQuery procedural?

Tags: jquery

I'm still learning jQuery, but the more I use jQuery, the more it appears that it is procedural rather than object-oriented. For example, I don't think I have seen or used any jQuery classes although I'm sure there are some used internally. All I do is method chaining, instead of constructing objects myself. e.g new Foo(). Also, the [jQuery documentation for plug-in development](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) does not even mention classes.

Is my observation correct that jQuery encourages you to expose only functions and methods and keep any custom classes internal when writing jQuery-based libraries? I'm not talking about writing jQuery plug-ins, but custom libraries that are unique to each application.

I'm coming from Java, so I'm kind of confused here.

Comment: (1) There are no classes in JS. (2) How can you chain *methods* without using objects? ;) Just because their construction doesn't involve the characters `new`, it doesn't mean you aren't creating/using objects.

Comment: jQuery is *way* better than OO!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery is mainly just a layer over the DOM API, coupled with some convenience methods like `each()` for iteration and enumeration. It smooths out a bit of what some may consider to be clunkiness in DOM API, and what most certainly is a lack of consistency across implementations.

It isn't a framework, and it isn't a language. It's really just there to give a better experience than the DOM API provides.

It utilizes the OOP features found in javascript, but it itself provides no specific programming paradigm. There are other libraries like [`prototypejs`](http://www.prototypejs.org/) and [`underscore`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) that are more focused in that area.

Comment: +1 for jQuery is not a framework but a library. Add a link to underscore & prototype please.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery is a lot more OO then procedural.

[`$(domNode)`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.4&fn=jQuery) returns a new jQuery object. If you take a look at the source the jQuery method returns a `new` object.

`$(domNode).foo` calls the method on the jQuery object.

Your confused by the fact that there is no `class` keyword.

```
function Constructor() {
    this.constructed = true;
}

var o = new Constructor;
alert(o.constructed);
```

As long as the `new` keyword is used then the function will be used as an object constructor. There is a very large difference between Java and JavaScript OO. JavaScript uses prototypical inheritance rather then class based inheritance.

The chaining in jQuery is done as illustrated [here](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.4&fn=jQuery.noConflict). Every method invoked on the jQuery object will return the jQuery object.

```
$(obj).css("foo").attr("bar"); // we can call both methods on $(obj)

var o = $(obj).css("foo"); // .css returns $(obj)
alert(o[0] === $(obj)[0]); // o & $(obj) point to the same DOM node
o.attr("bar");
```

Comment: This takes a little different perspective that which I interpreted from the question (not to say mine is right). +1 for the insight into how jQuery is implemented as opposed to how it is utilized.

Comment: @patrickdw I thought he was saying the jQuery source was written in a procedural style.

Answer (score 2):

If the documentation didn't mention Class or stuff like this is it because jQuery is definitively not a language. It is an API written in Javascript and Javascript is a [Prototype programing language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming).

Comment: +1 for jQuery is not a language. Also a prototype language is still object-orientated.

Comment: jQuery is not a language indeed. People keep forgetting that. :) However, it is written *in* a language and could have been written in a procedural or an object oriented style, making the question very valid. Tom didn't suggest anywhere that jQuery is a language itself.

Comment: @Raynos of cause it is OO I didn't say that is not. :)

Comment: meant to say that prototypical OO is a flavour of OO just like class based inheritance is a flavour of OO.

Comment: @Raynos yes absolutely, one of the first prototype base was Object Lisp

Answer (score 1):

It's not jQuery that is bothering you, it's JavaScript :) 
JavaScript is prototype based language and the OO style there is a bit different. It's actually simulated OO via prototypes (for more, you can read here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Prototype-based )

jQuery has a lot to do with OO.
The `$` function is actually a factory method for creating jQuery objects - that's why you are not writing yourself `new Foo()`

The stuff that begins with $. are more like utility methods.
For example (from wikipedia) a mapping function in jQuery :

```
$.each([1,2,3], function(){
  document.write(this + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

JQuery is OO indeed. Maybe you didn't see classes because classes in JavaScript look a bit different. They are actually functions with a little extra:

```
// Yes, this function is actually a class constructor.
function Demo(a)
{
  // A property is declared easily and can be unset as well. 
  this.a = a;
}

// You can add functions to the prototype, but you can also
// declare functions and assign them to this.functionName in the constructor.
Demo.prototype.test = function()
{
  alert(this.a);
}

d = new Demo('Hello world');
d.test();
```

So there's never the word 'class' or 'object' or anything like that, and still I'm using an object oriented model.
Also, any 'loose' function is actually a method of the window object, just as any variable is a property of the window object. So JavaScript is entirely OO, although it tries very hard to hide that fact. :D

Comment: @GolezTroi loose functions are properties of the window object.